# Postgresql and Vault. ERROR: permission denied for relation example

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql, hashicorp-vault

I am generating dynamic credentials with vault (v0.10.1) for postgresql (9.5.13) on a machine with Ubuntu 18.04, but with the generated credentials I am able to login and see the table (\dt), but I cannot select values from it:

```
    pgdbdemo=> select * from example;
    ERROR:  permission denied for relation example
```

If I grant the permissions manually on postgresql with the postgres user works and then the select is then executed.

```
    pgdbdemo=# GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "v-userpass-readonly-0tqxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-1xxxxxxxxx9";
    GRANT
```

But I would want them integrated with the following vault role that seems to be ignoring the GRANT statement despite of creating the credential with the right TTL, etc:

```
    vault write database/roles/readonly \
    db_name="pgdbdemo" \
    creation_statements="CREATE ROLE \"{{name}}\" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '{{password}}' VALID UNTIL '{{expiration}}'; \
    GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO \"{{name}}\";" \
    default_ttl="10m" \
    max_ttl="24h"
```

My Vault database configuration:

```
    vault write database/config/pgdbdemo \ 
    plugin_name="postgresql-database-plugin" \ 
    allowed_roles="readonly" \ 
    connection_url="postgresql://postgres:pgpass@127.0.0.1:5432?sslmode=disable" \
```

How can I get the select working with these dynamic credentials?

Comment: What you did so far seems correct; the postgres user that you assigned to Vault in the configuration is enabled to grant permissions?

Comment: It should, The user is "postgres" and I have used it on the connection_url part of the configuration.

Comment: Could you please show us a sample of your secret engine configuration (database/config/)?

Comment: vault write database/config/pgdbdemo \
  plugin_name="postgresql-database-plugin" \
  allowed_roles="readonly" \
connection_url="postgresql://postgres:pgpass@127.0.0.1:5432?sslmode=disable" \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the database you are connecting to in the configuration: `connection_url="postgresql://postgres:pgpass@127.0.0.1:5432/pgdbdemo?sslmode=disable"`

Otherwise, according to the [official Postgres documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html), it will connect to the database with the same name as the user name, in this case `postgres`

Comment: That was it! Thanks!